# Inner of 3 for loops won't run unless value from outer loops is non-zero, but only when subtracting inside the innermost loop

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array, char

I know that this is quite a long and probably confusing post... but I really have no idea what could be causing this... so i did the best I could at explaining. I am not sure how to describe the problem succinctly, which has made it rather difficult for me to look for other solutions.

Anyway, First a slight bit of background. This program is reading through a 2D array in all of a possible 8 directions looking for a word (The program is basically an automated word find).

I have the 2D array and I am searching through it, looking for a given string. To do this, I have 3 loops:

- The first loop (looping x) chooses the starting x-coordinate
- The second loop (looping y) chooses the starting y-coordinate
- The last loop (looping L) checks for a word of length L starting at the positions given by (x,y) coordinates from the outer loops.

However, It seems the program does not enter the loop for L until the outer loops have increased to 1. Because of this, I cannot start a search for a word in column 1 (x=0), the first one that gets accessed is column 2 (x=1). **It is almost as if there is an if statement preventing the for loop from running when the values from either of the other two loops are below 1**. What is more, this **ONLY HAPPENS** When I am subtracting index locations of the array, not when I am adding them.

To clarify on that last point, I am searching for words by adding chars to a string one at a time. So when reading forward, a three letter word 'cat' would consist of a string 'c' at location x, then we add to the string the char 'a' at location x+1, then we add to that string the char 't' from location x+2. This basically gets writted as arr[x+L][y], to search forward for a word. HOWEVER, I also want to find words written backwards. so for that I have a loop the adds arr[x-L][y]. **It seems that this error ONLY happens when I am subtracting L from the indicies in my array, and only happens to the value that it is subtracted from (so for [x-1][y], x=0 does not go into the for loop, but y=0 DOES.**

Here is the (shortened) code:

```
public void searchPuzzle(String[][] Puzzle){

    //For Each Coordinate X,Y
    for(int x=0; x<Puzzle.length; x++){//For each x position

        for(int y=0; y<Puzzle[x].length; y++){//For each y position

            //RESET or INITAITE strings for searching in all 8 directions
            String F="", B="", U="", D="", DiFU="", DiFD="", DiBU="", DiBD="";

            //SEARCH FORWARD
            for(int L = 0; L < Puzzle.length-x; L++){ //search for word of length L
                F = F+Puzzle[x+L][y];
                //System.out.println(F);
                if(isWord(F)){
                    //System.out.println(F);
                }
            }


            //SEARCH BACK 
            System.out.println("X:" + x + " Y: "+y);
            for(int L = 0; L < x; L++){ //search for word of
                System.out.println("X:" + x + " Y: "+y);
                B = B+Puzzle[x-L][y];
                System.out.println(B);
                if(isWord(B)){
                    //System.out.println(B);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("--");

            //SEARCH DIAGONALLY - BACK & UP
            for(int L = 0; L < smaller(x,y); L++){
                DiBU = DiBU+Puzzle[x-L][y-L];
                if(isWord(DiBU)){
                    //System.out.println(DiBU);
                }
            }
```

- SEARCH FORWARD

works perfectly (Because F+Puzzle[x+L][y] involves only addition).
So for this one the program to start reading at arr[0][0], as it should.

- SEARCH BACK

has the error I mentioned, but only the x value is wrong. This means that x=0 never gets passed into the loop SEARCH BACK, ans as a result the loop starts with x=1. Note that the code has B+Puzzle[x-L][y]
So for this one the program to start reading at arr[1][0].

- SEARCH DIAGONALLY - BACK & UP

has this error for both x AND Y. Because of "DiBU+Puzzle[x-L][y-L]", BOTH x=0 and y=0 do not go into the loop. And so
So for this one the program to start reading at arr[1][1].

EDIT: I have tried simply subtracting 1 (as in B+Puzzle[x-L-1][y]), however this just causes it to start in the right place but end one column to short.

**TL;DR**
Innermost of three for loops cannot be read unless the value of the outer two loops is above 0. But this problem only occurs if I am subtracting values from the indices of an array inside the said innermost For Loop.

Comment: I suggest you step through the code in your debugger to get an understanding of what your program is really doing.

Comment: I don't use an IDE... I was taught not to start learning programming with one, and then I just never really got a feel for using one even once I knew the basics.

I can include output from the print statements surrounding the code, which has provided me with some insight... but i cannot get it to format correctly here

Comment: use better variable names... and stick to a standard naming convention. `L` in capital letter for an iterator variable, `F` for a variable, ouch.

Comment: IDEs are designed to improve your productivity and the quality of your application. You can debug you program by adding a break point and click `Debug` next to run.  Once you get used to an IDE (which does take some time) you may wonder why you did it any other way.

Comment: I was not aware uppercase variables were so frowned upon... for what it is worth I do not usually use them...

Comment: IF it is sort of a "religious" thing against debuggers/IDEs, you can "debug" just by strategically adding `System.out.println` (the poor man's debugger) and checking the flow path, and the relevant variables at each point. Better with a debugger, though.

Comment: That is exactly what I did. I tried to include the output here but it looked terrible so:
This is the output of the SEARCH BACKWARDS loop:https://www.dropbox.com/s/si1ynvlw84r74jr/Screenshot%20from%202012-11-05%2004%3A04%3A27.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is simpler to separate the forwards and backwards searches, at least until you get it all working. Do one thing at a time, and do it carefully.

The reason for not doing any iterations of the second loop if x is zero lies in the loop condition:

```
  for(int L = 0; L < x; L++)
```

L is never less than 0, and so if x is 0 the condition  L < x is never met, and the loop does zero iterations.

Suppose y is 0 and x is 2. The elements [2][0], [1][0], and [0][0] could be a three letter word. You will only do two iterations, for L=0 and L=1.

Both problems would be fixed by doing one more iteration by changing the condition to L <= x.

It is very, very important to think about your loop conditions. In many simple cases a "<" test is appropriate, but not always. In this case, L==x results in looking at element 0 of the array, which you want.

Comment: This is fairly obvious. My apologies (for the stupid question, and 2 weeks late response). This is what you get for posting questions here at 3am I guess. Thanks for your help none the less.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an logical issue with :

```
       //SEARCH BACK 
        for(int L = 0; L < x; L++){ //search for word of
            B = B+Puzzle[x-L][y];
            //System.out.println(B);
            if(isWord(B)){
                //System.out.println(B);
            }
        }
```

If the word `CAT` is written `TAC` at the beginning of your matrix, you will not find it.
Maybe you want to do :

```
       //SEARCH BACK 
        for(int L = Puzzle.length-x - 1; L >=0 ; L--){ 
            B = B+Puzzle[L-x][y];
            //System.out.println(B);
            if(isWord(B)){
                //System.out.println(B);
            }
        }
```

So, ***why do you you search backwards***??? You can rather concatenates a word on the other side each time you search forward. Which means :

```
       String forwardword;
       String backwardword; 
       for(int L = 0; L < Puzzle.length-x; L++){ //search for word of length L
            forwardword = forwardword +Puzzle[x+L][y];
            backwardword = Puzzle[x+L][y] + backwardword; // <<HERE

            if(isWord(forwardword)){
                //System.out.println(forwardword);
            }
            if(isWord(backwardword)){
                //System.out.println(backwardword);
            }                

        }
```

Comment: Hm... seems like it should work. However when I tried it, some of the words did not come out correctly (namely, it tended to repeat some letters for no apparent reason).

Although you may be correct in that your method works better... I am still bothered by how on earth a for loop will not run just because of the value of a loop it is inside of, and how the subtraction bit comes into this... I cant think of a logical reason for it... which really bugs me.

Comment: wait , which option are you talking about??

Comment: `int L = 0; L < x`. If `x = 0` then it will not be executed. which show that this code is wrong.

Comment: Wow. Okay. Yeah I am very stupid. Those should all be less than or equals to. This is what you get for posting here at 3am. Thanks guys! Sorry my question ended up to be so stupid.